# .NET Compact Framework GetHashCode(Object) equivalent

Tags: .net, compact-framework

What is .NET Compact Framework equivalent for following method? Is there any P/Invoke call available?

System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.GetHashCode(Object)

I am in middle of an open source project port to .NET Compact Framework.

Answer (score 2):

There is no PInvoke call possible for this method.  RuntimeHelpers.GetHashCode() really just calls into an internal CLR method (Object.InternalGetHashCode).  It's not possible to PInovke into such a function.

This method is really just calling Object.GetHashCode() in a non-virtual way.  Unfortunately there is not a way to do this statically.  C# does not support calling a method on a given object non-virtually (CLR considers this non-veriable code).

Your best bet is to call into Object.InternalGetHasheCode via reflection.  You'll have to check and see if that method is implemented on the Compact Framework though.  My expectation is that it will be but I don't have a mscorlib for CF handy.

Documentation for RuntimeHelpers.GetHashCode: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/11tbk3h9.aspx

Comment: It's not unverifiable to use `call` instead of `callvirt`, it's just impossible to express in C#. You can write verifiable CIL that does it, either in an IL project, or through `Reflection.Emit()`.

Answer (score 1):

I've written some code that obtains a delegate to an identity hash code method that works on both the standard and Compact Frameworks, though it relies on undocumented internals of Compact Framework to do so.  I've forgotten the actual P/Invoke call (it's an ordinal export from `mscoree.dll`); this just grabs the internal P/Invoke prototype out of `mscorlib` by name.

```
private static readonly Func<object, int> _IdentityHashCode;

static ClassName()
{
    Assembly mscorlib = typeof(object).Assembly;
    Type t;
    MethodInfo mi;

    // Try the official way first.
    if ((t = mscorlib.GetType("System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers")) != null)
    {
        if ((mi = t.GetMethod("GetHashCode", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static)) != null)
        {
            _IdentityHashCode = (Func<object, int>)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<object, int>), null, mi);
            return;
        }
    }

    // On Compact Framework we have to go in through the back door.
    if ((t = mscorlib.GetType("System.PInvoke.EE")) != null)
    {
        if ((mi = t.GetMethod("Object_GetHashCode", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static)) != null)
        {
            _IdentityHashCode = (Func<object, int>)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<object, int>), null, mi);
            return;
        }
    }

    _IdentityHashCode = LastDitchHashFunction;
}

private static int LastDitchHashFunction(object obj)
{
    // A legal if very inefficient implementation ...
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote [A is A](https://bitbucket.org/JonHanna/aisa) to deal with this issue without depending on `Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers` (not available in every runtime version), `Reflection.Emit` (same problem) or PInvoking to an undocumented method (which could change).

It does the same thing as the `Reflection.Emit` approach, but is written in directly in the relevant CIL:

```
ldarg.1
call instance int32 [mscorlib]System.Object::GetHashCode()
ret
```

As CIL goes, this is as simple as it comes - albeit a stupid idea 99% of the time*, because `GetHashCode()` is virtual for a reason, and hence 99% of the time `call` instead of `callvirt` would be a bug. As such, while the fact that C# uses `callvirt` with non-virtual methods is debated by some (well, me), it really does make sense that there's no C# way of expressing this directly.

*Part of the inspiration behind the project's name; the law of identity goes back to Aristotle, but "A is A" is most closely associated with a philosophy that I consider stupid 99% of the time.

Comment: When using `call` instead of `callvirt`, you should make sure to include an explicit check for null prior to the call, or you could end up in a place where accessing `this` in managed code produces a `NullReferenceException`.

Comment: @280Z28 sometimes one's very reason for using `call` instead of `callvirt` can be precisely to not have an implicit null check. This isn't one of those cases, though it is one where not checking for null still works fine and has the desired result (it returns `0`).